# Game created in Unity is too slow & crashes after built to to iPad. How to fix this?

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine, ipad, didreceivememorywarning

I have built my first game in Unity called Aesopicas. It runs great on my Mac in Unity's game window, but after I build it to my iPad the game become very slow and crashes. I have basically created 9 different levels by creating level 1 and then tweaking all the other levels slightly. I thinks it's something wrong with memory but I have no idea where to even start. Here is the console message from Xcode:

```
2019-12-20 23:34:33.181112+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158175] [DYMTLInitPlatform] platform initialization successful
2019-12-20 23:34:33.389544+0100 Aesopicas[1856:157832] Built from '2019.1/staging' branch, Version '2019.1.7f1 (f3c4928e5742)', Build type 'Development', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp'
2019-12-20 23:34:33.419052+0100 Aesopicas[1856:157832] -> registered mono modules 0x10262cc40
-> applicationDidFinishLaunching()
PlayerConnection initialized from /var/containers/Bundle/Application/DE82F3AF-5A93-4309-9E79-166CF7A792FD/Aesopicas.app/Data (debug = 0)
PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55000
Multi-casting "[IP] 192.168.1.177 [Port] 55000 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 1809220790 [EditorId] 3469678780 [Version] 1048832 [Id] iPhonePlayer(Daniels-iPad):56000 [Debug] 0 [PackageName] iPhonePlayer" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55000]
PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55000]
2019-12-20 23:34:33.826422+0100 Aesopicas[1856:157832] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2019-12-20 23:34:33.830255+0100 Aesopicas[1856:157832] Metal API Validation Disabled
-> applicationDidBecomeActive()
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Initializing Metal device caps: Apple A7 GPU
Initialize engine version: 2019.1.7f1 (f3c4928e5742)
2019-12-20 23:34:38.049646+0100 Aesopicas[1856:157832] [Common] _BSMachError: port bd03; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2019-12-20 23:34:38.051391+0100 Aesopicas[1856:157832] [Common] _BSMachError: port bd03; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
UnloadTime: 8.291500 ms
Setting up 1 worker threads for Enlighten.
  Thread -> id: 171047000 -> priority: 1 
2019-12-20 23:34:40.541065+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158194] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x11154a180] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-12-20 23:34:40.541536+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158194] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x11154a180] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-12-20 23:34:40.544719+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158194] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-12-20 23:34:40.546116+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158194] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-12-20 23:34:41.489586+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158161] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x1115589a0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-12-20 23:34:41.495355+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158161] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C2.1:2][0x1115589a0] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-12-20 23:34:41.496473+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158161] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-12-20 23:34:41.496712+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158161] TIC Read Status [2:0x0]: 1:57
2019-12-20 23:34:41.762752+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158194] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x11290c790] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-12-20 23:34:41.763611+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158194] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C3.1:2][0x11290c790] get output frames failed, state 8196
2019-12-20 23:34:41.765555+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158194] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
2019-12-20 23:34:41.765994+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158194] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
Unloading 5 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 19.088167 ms
System memory in use before: 66.6 MB.
System memory in use after: 31.8 MB.

Unloading 18 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 607.
Total: 26.403167 ms (FindLiveObjects: 5.507875 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.042042 ms MarkObjects: 13.276292 ms  DeleteObjects: 7.574125 ms)

Unloading 1 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 5.782208 ms
System memory in use before: 36.1 MB.
System memory in use after: 36.1 MB.

Unloading 19 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 588.
Total: 2.950250 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.425167 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.035500 ms MarkObjects: 1.722833 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.764625 ms)

Unloading 1 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 23.509542 ms
System memory in use before: 35.1 MB.
System memory in use after: 35.1 MB.

Unloading 1 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 589.
Total: 5.186708 ms (FindLiveObjects: 1.129708 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.097625 ms MarkObjects: 3.872875 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.078333 ms)

Unloading 0 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 15.703042 ms
System memory in use before: 35.1 MB.
System memory in use after: 35.1 MB.

Unloading 1 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 589.
Total: 4.580750 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.938375 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.043042 ms MarkObjects: 3.493833 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.103708 ms)

Unloading 2 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/PostProcessing/Uber' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/PostProcessing/Uber' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/PostProcessing/FinalPass' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
WARNING: Shader Unsupported: 'Hidden/PostProcessing/FinalPass' - Pass '' has no vertex shader
UnloadTime: 31.216750 ms
System memory in use before: 65.6 MB.
System memory in use after: 61.5 MB.

Unloading 11 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 1107.
Total: 14.885458 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.747792 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.748958 ms MarkObjects: 8.447125 ms  DeleteObjects: 4.937375 ms)

2019-12-20 23:35:22.009078+0100 Aesopicas[1856:158229] Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED
WARNING -> applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning()
Unloading 2 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 93.769542 ms
System memory in use before: 62.4 MB.
System memory in use after: 62.4 MB.

Unloading 30 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 1127.
Total: 25.216167 ms (FindLiveObjects: 1.501542 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.222125 ms MarkObjects: 22.520708 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.969083 ms)

WARNING -> applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning()
Unloading 0 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 51.854375 ms
System memory in use before: 62.2 MB.
System memory in use after: 62.2 MB.

Unloading 34 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 1116.
Total: 31.331333 ms (FindLiveObjects: 1.685333 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.304125 ms MarkObjects: 28.938500 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.399167 ms)

WARNING -> applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning()
Unloading 3 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
UnloadTime: 47.544875 ms
System memory in use before: 97.2 MB.
System memory in use after: 96.9 MB.

Unloading 29 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 1149.
Total: 32.087625 ms (FindLiveObjects: 1.995542 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.477167 ms MarkObjects: 27.473792 ms  DeleteObjects: 2.138667 ms)

WARNING -> applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning()
Aesopicas was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
(lldb)
```

Comment: You would need to read about optimizing for mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your unity **graphic APIs** in player settings , mobiles uses GSL2 and GSL3 don’t use Vulkan for simple graphics game since Vulkan is more faster on high-end mobile devices.

1. Change graphic APIs
2. Be sure to profile your game to check if the issue related to your level performance
3. Build the game and see if the issue is still persisting.